# Error pushing to cocoapod trunk

Tags: cocoapods

I'm receiving "[!] An internal server error occurred. Please check for any known status issues at https://twitter.com/CocoaPods and try again later." when trying to push a new version of my pod NRSPieChart. I just created this last night and it's the my first time creating my own pod. Everything seemed to have worked on the first submission. Today I updated my version in order to expand my example project and expand my README.md file to provide better Usage instructions. Upon trying to push to Trunk though I get the above error. Since I'm new to this my assumption is I've done something wrong rather than coincidentally there's an error with the spec repo?

I saw one reference to the s.source tag might need a hard code tag string. I tried that but same problem. This is the before (commented line) and after of that attempt:

# s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/neils4fun/NRSPieChart.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/neils4fun/NRSPieChart.git", :tag => "0.1.1" }

Comment: I'm having the same error today. It worked yesterday so it seems that actually something broke on server. Also see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6474

Answer (score 0):

Update: I tried again "later" as the error message suggested and it's now working. I made no changes to my pod code or pod spec, so chalk this up to something internal on the cocoa pods side of the fence.